# XCodeで"Open Recent"でプロジェクトを開けない

Tags: xcode

標題の件、不便で困っております。
どなたかお知恵をお貸しいただければと思います。

XCodeで、一度開いたプロジェクトを`Open Recent`から開こうとすると

```
The document "XXXX" could be opened. The file doesn't exist.
```

と小ウィンドウで表示されてしまいます(`XXXX`にはファイル名が入ります)。
リストに開いたファイルの一覧は出るのですが…。
もちろん該当のファイルは、一度XCodeで開いてからは移動させておりません。

1つ関係があるかもと思っている要因は、あるディレクトリへの<strike>エイリアス</strike>シンボリックリンクを張っていて、そこから`*.xcodeproject`などのプロジェクトファイルがある場所までたどって、そこでダブルクリック等でプロジェクトを開いている点です。
ですが、`Open Recent`から開けない件との因果関係は私にわからず。。。
ちなみにXCode起動直後の画面の右側に表示される履歴からはプロジェクトを開くことができます。

xcodeのバージョン:15.0.1

よろしくお願いいたします。

2024/02/16 8:56 編集:シンボリックリンクとエイリアスを取り違えていた点を修正。